# customize access 2010 Ribbon

Tags: microsoft-access, ribbon

I have notice Microsoft provide 2 verions of guildline to customize Access Ribbon, one for version 2007, other for 2010.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/customize-the-ribbon-HA010211415.aspx
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/customize-the-ribbon-HA010355697.aspx

The 2007 version is input XML into the database.
The 2010 version is not.

I want to know my understanding below is correct or not?

*the "XML" method go with the database file, so the same database file (accdb) keep the Ribbon setting, apply the setting when open in another machine.*

*the "non XML" method save the setting in machine, so if I need the same Ribbon on another machine, I must set it again.*

**One more question, I am using the access 2010, so if my above understaning is correct, if I want to keep the Ribbon setting in file, I must use the XML method from version 2007?**

Comment: Thanks Charlie. But actually it is not exactly what I want.

I only want the customization apply to one specific accdb file (database system) only. I don't want to affect the user Access 2010 default Ribbon/QAT. The customization only effective when user open my accdb file.

Will the 2007 method better suit my case?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the method specific to Office 2010. Office 2010 applications hold ribbon setting in a "User Interface" or UI file. For Access 2010 it is called `Access.officeUI`. Below is more information how to deploy custom ribbon settings.

> The Microsoft Office Fluent User Interface (UI) includes the Ribbon
>   and the Quick Access Toolbar. These items are customized by using XML
>   to define the components of the UI and with programming code, also
>   known as callback procedures, to give the components their
>   functionality. Customizing the UI is simply a matter of updating the
>   XML and, optionally, updating or adding new callback procedures.

This is from the MSDN article [Deploying a Customized Ribbon and Quick Access Toolbar in Office 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee704589%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Charlie, I have read your MSDN article, but it is not exactly what I want. The Access.officeUI file approach will apply the setting on the Access 2010, no matter which database file open. I only want the setting apply to specific database file only.